# is it ok to take random actions while training a3c as in below code

Tags: reinforcement-learning, pytorch, a3c

i am trying to train an A3C algorithm but I am getting same output in the multinomial function.

can I train the A3C with random actions as in below code.

can someone expert comment.

```
while count<max_timesteps-1:
            value, action_values, (hx, cx) = model((Variable(state.unsqueeze(0)), (hx, cx)))
            prob = F.softmax(action_values,dim = -1)
            log_prob = F.log_softmax(action_values, dim=-1)
            print(log_prob.shape)
            print("log_prob: ",log_prob)
            entropy = -(log_prob * prob).sum(1, keepdim=True)
            entropies.append(entropy)
            actn = np.random.randn(3)
            action = actn.argmax()
            log_prob = log_prob[0,action]
            # print("log_prob ",log_prob)
            # print("action ",action)
            state, reward, done = env.step(action)
            done = (done or count == max_timesteps-2)
            reward = max(min(reward, 1), -1)
```